# Font Awsome icons not loading properly in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, icons

I'm using 'Font Awsome' icons in my application. Code looks like this

```
  ..
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/newLayout/font-awesome.min.css">  
  ...
  <style>
  .icon-batch-icons-webfont-6:before {
  content: "d";
  }
  </style>

  <body>
  ...
  <form name="loginForm" >
  <i class="icon-batch-icons-webfont-6"></i> 
  <input type="text"  placeholder="User Name" id="username" name="username" />
  ...
  </form>

  ..

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="../js/newLayout/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  </body>
```

Problem is, sometimes in IE8 icons are not loading!!
but some times they are working fine in IE8. 
i've checked all the blogs,google,stackoverflow and tried all tricks. I could'nt find where the exact problem is. 
 can anyone help me with this?
-Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [**How to ask a good question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Paulie_D after the quality on SO today, for the first time ever I've run out of votes.

Comment: Question improved. please check it! @Paulie_D